# Crude 3d game that starts with you viewing souls, represented as stars in space, ends with man in a cage

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I'm pretty sure I played this over ten years ago, on a Windows system, first person perspective. At the beginning of the game, you're in what looks like outer space. You can pick from what look like stars, and each has a brief profile of a person. I think there was only one that you could actually pick, which described someone with suicidal impulses. Once you pick it, you wind up in a dimly house or apartment, maybe starting in the bathroom.

The house seems deserted. I think it has a kitchen, with nothing in the cabinets or refrigerator, a living room with a TV that only shows static, and another room that's wallpapered with variations on a drawing of two palm trees. You can't exit via the doors. Eventually, if you poke around enough, you find a hidden door, leading to an enclosed room that holds a man in a cage. You have the option to execute him by electrifying the cage.

I don't remember if it was explained in the game, but you're inhabiting the body of someone who committed suicide, probably after abducting the man in the cage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was writing the question, more details occurred to me, and I found my game by searching for `video game suicide man in a cage`, *[The Static Speaks My Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Static_Speaks_My_Name)*

> The game takes place in a first-person perspective, and starts out in an indistinct black space, with a grey morphing blob; walking up to it displays a text about a person named Jacob Ernholtz who has committed suicide by hanging at the age of 31. The perspective then shifts to Ernholtz as he is waking up in his apartment; the player – as Ernholtz – must then perform a few menial tasks in the apartment, which is dimly lit with all the doors and windows boarded up. Exploring the apartment reveals that Ernholtz has developed an obsession with a painting of two palm trees and its painter Jason Malone, who a news article pinned to the refrigerator claims has disappeared. The player can also find a hidden doorway behind a bookcase finding Malone in a cage – the player is given the option to either unlock the cage or electrocute Malone. The player then must go to a final room and commit suicide by hanging; the perspective then shifts back to the black space with multiple grey blobs, each with another person's name and method of suicide.

So I got some details of the opening wrong, as well as when you see other people as options, but the other details are about right.

### Trailer

Comment: Can't see why this one didn't catch on.